# Items purchased not Appearing in the inventory when they're purchased

Tags: unity, c#

I purchase Items from my shop menu In-Game it doesn't show in my Inventory these are the pictures from the game shop and when i purchase something and when i open the inventory menu:

[image: Opening Shop menu to buy an Item]

[image: When i purchase the item and the money is subtracted from my Coins text]

[image: Empty Inventory Menu after purchase]

These are the scripts I'm using for the Inventory and the shop:

**Shop Manager**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.GameFoundation;

public class ShopManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int[,] shopItems = new int[9, 9];
    public float coins;
    public Text CoinsTXT;


    void Start()
    {
        CoinsTXT.text = "" + coins.ToString();

        //ID's
        shopItems[1, 1] = 1;
        shopItems[1, 2] = 2;
        shopItems[1, 3] = 3;
        shopItems[1, 4] = 4;
        shopItems[1, 5] = 5;
        shopItems[1, 6] = 6;
        shopItems[1, 7] = 7;
        shopItems[1, 8] = 8;

        //Price
        shopItems[2, 1] = 10;
        shopItems[2, 2] = 20;
        shopItems[2, 3] = 30;
        shopItems[2, 4] = 40;
        shopItems[2, 5] = 50;
        shopItems[2, 6] = 65;
        shopItems[2, 7] = 110;
        shopItems[2, 8] = 150;

    }


    public void Buy()
    {
        GameObject ButtonRef = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Events").GetComponent<EventSystem>().currentSelectedGameObject;

        if (coins >= shopItems[2, ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().ItemID])
        {
            coins -= shopItems[2, ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().ItemID];
            CoinsTXT.text = "Coins:" + coins.ToString();

            Item yourItem = new Item(); //get your Item from ID

            GameEvents.gameEvents.ItemPurchaseMade(yourItem);
        }


    }
}
```

**GameEvents Script:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameEvents : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameEvents gameEvents;

    private void Awake()
    {
        gameEvents = this;
    }

    public event Action<Item> onItemPurchase;

    public void ItemPurchaseMade(Item ItemID)
    {
        if (onItemPurchase != null)
        {
            onItemPurchase(ItemID);
        }
    }
}
```

**Inventory Script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{

    private List<Item> itemList;

    public void Start()
    {
        itemList = new List<Item>();

        GameEvents.gameEvents.onItemPurchase += AddItem;

        Debug.Log("Inventory");
    }

    public void AddItem(Item item)
    {
        itemList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Even when i remove `Debug.Log` it still shows nothing.

Comment: You've shown code that adds a new empty Item object to a list of items. You have not shown code that spawns or reveals a visible game object to represent that item in the UI, or changes the visible state of an existing game object. Did you mean to add code that does one of these things?

Comment: sorry, I don't have this kinda code what should this code be called? and do I hook it up with the inventory ?

Comment: It sounds to me like you might want to go back to some basic Unity tutorials, if the concept of instantiating or activating a game object is unfamiliar.

Comment: yeah i'll try that thanks